# Heroku Ruby Deployment H10 ERROR Port Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, port

I've just finished writing and reworking some code for a website, and when I try to host it on Heroku I get this error:

`2021-04-18T01:13:48.793626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bg-demo-site.herokuapp.com request_id=824dceb7-52c1-403d-b101-e54b0af4aa48 fwd="my-ip-here" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Looking up error code H10, I see that it's some sort of Port error, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to fix it. I've added a port in the heroku config vars, I've changed the port in the config/puma.rb file to be the same as the heroku config var *[Name: PORT2 Value: 3000]* ...

If anybody could give me a bit of insight as to what exactly needs fixing, I would be pretty grateful. This is bugging the heck outta me.

Thanks guys.

Comment: "I've added a port in the heroku config vars"—that's not how it works. You don't get to pick your port on Heroku; you must _use_ the port it _assigns you_.

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#create-a-procfile